# Regex match string but do not match when containing certain elements

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to make a regex match with a series of similar strings but not match others that meet another certain criteria.  I *almost* got it right but am having trouble when trying to exclude certain name words of a random length.

And I am trying to parse a full string from the middle part, here are some examples.

Examples of strings I want to match and what to extract from them:

```
You see a tall athletic dark-brown-haired adult man with dark olive skin and hazel eyes.
You see a short fat yellow-haired youthful man with pale skin and blue eyes.
```

I want to extract these from the above examples:

```
tall athletic dark-brown-haired adult man with dark olive skin and hazel eyes
short fat yellow-haired youthful man with pale skin and blue eyes
```

Examples of strings I DO NOT want to match and just disregard:  (anything ending in (yourself!) or , whom you know as )

```
You see a masked tall-height heavy man with white skin (yourself!).
You see a furrow-browed older man with cropped pepper-gray hair, whom you know as Richard.
You see a younger man with cropped blue hair, whom you know as Bob.
```

I have a limited understanding of regex and these are above me.  Any help would be appreciated.

What I have so far (partially working):

```
^You see (a|an) (.*?)(?<!, whom you know as Steve.|\(yourself!\).)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten `(a|an)`  to `an?`  if you don't want to capture that part separately.

The capture group for the part that you are interested `(.*)` in does not have to be non greedy, as it should end right before the dot at the end of the string.

Excluding the lines using a negative lookahead `(?!`, instead of a negative lookbehind:

```
^You see an? (?!.*(?:, whom you know as\b|\(yourself!\)))(.*)\.$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BfAYOm/1)

Comment: Thanks that did what I needed perfectly, and I learned a few new tricks!